# Check if UK date is bewteen two dates in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I need to check that a UK date, stored as string in the format dd/mm/yyyy in a database table (`postmeta.event_date`), is between two dates using SLQ format `BETWEEN 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND 'yyyy-mm-dd+28'`. I'm ok with working out the dates to check between, it's the date to check that I'm having issues with because it is in the wrong format for SQL.

I have no way of changing the format of the date to check, as it is attached to a post, and I don't know what posts to get out of the database until I can check if they are between my chosen dates...

Any ideas if this is possible, or am I looking at two queries (grab all the posts get the IDs of the ones that I actually want by checking the data in PHP)? Thanks.

Comment: How is the UK formatted date stored? As a string, datetime, timestamp?
Are the two dates fixed or do they change? Is the interval always 28 days?

Comment: @h00ligan - UK date is stored as a string, and the two dates do change (first is today and second is today+28), but I'm ok with that part - it's having the date in the wrong format that is giving me a headache! Edited question to clairfy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to convert your date would be to use `str_to_date`:

```
STR_TO_DATE(event_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

This converts your date to something you can use in your `BETWEEN` formula.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Looks promising, just trying to edit the PHP that creates the SQL to test.

Comment: Tested and working, thanks very much for your help (and the pointer to the writeup about the function).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following construction:

STR_TO_DATE(postmeta.event_date, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND 'yyyy-mm-dd' + INTERVAL 28 DAY

However using a custom date format, such that is not supported natively by the database, in a column that can used for filtering is commonly a bad design, unless maybe one knows exactly what they are doing.

A query relying on the filter provided above will work, but it won't be very efficient as such range lookup cannot be optimized through indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. In an ideal world, it would be a date stamp, but the data is being added to the DB by Wordpress (using the 'Custom Fields' feature), and without further investigation I'm not sure that I can filter it to the correct format for storage in the DB, and then back the other way for display on the Edit Post screen.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
WHERE event_date BETWEEN 'yyyy-mm-dd' AND DATE_ADD('yyyy-mm-dd', INTERVAL 28 DAY)
```

Obviously the `yyyy-mm-dd` will be replaced with actual values:

```
WHERE event_date BETWEEN '2011-05-11' AND DATE_ADD('2011-05-11', INTERVAL 28 DAY)
```

If your date string is not in the expected format, you'll have to parse it first. You can do that in PHP or use `STR_TO_DATE`.

```
WHERE event_date 
BETWEEN 
    STR_TO_DATE('01/05/2011','%d/%m/%Y') AND
    DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('01/05/2011','%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL 28 DAY)
```

Comment: I think he specifically mentions that he needs help with the conversion of the format of the date.

Comment: Should probably show the actual date format he's using in the question then.

Comment: Thanks @Cylindric, but it's not the interval that I need help with, it's the fact that the date I need to check in the database is a UK date in the dd/mm/yyyy format, which MySQL doesn't like.

Comment: Thanks, someone else just suggested that and I'm testing now, but from the description it should achieve what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is period from today - to the next 28 days

```
  $now = mktime();
  //set your period date
  $from = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m",$now), date("d",$now), date("Y",$now));
  $to   = mktime(23, 59, 59, date("m",$now), date("d",$now)+28, date("Y",$now));
```

HERE IS YOUR QUERY

```
 SELECT * FROM `postmeta` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`event_date`)>='".$from."' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`event_date`)<='".$to."'
```